# Is there a way to declare associative arrays in bash using ip addresses as indices?

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to do this:

```
declare -a ip_array=( [127.0.0.1]=127.1.1.1 [127.1.1.1]=127.0.0.1 )
```

However bash complains as it thinks the decimals are operators:

```
bash: 127.0.0.1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "127.0.0.1")
```

I tried using single and double quotes but it seems to evaluate arithmetically every time.

EDIT: I did not notice that there is a difference between lowercase -a and uppercase -A options when declaring an array.

Comment: You need an associative array for that: use `declare -A ...` -- "plain" arrays with "declare -a" are numerically indexed.

Comment: @glennjackman: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[- +] a declares NAMEs as an indexed array (deleting with + acceptable syntax, but results in an error message)

[- +] A declares NAMEs as an associative array

Try this:

```
declare -A AR=( [127.0.0.1]=127.1.1.1 [127.1.1.1]=127.0.0.1 ); echo ${AR[@]};
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what the problem was and how this fixes it.

Comment: @Barmar fixed :-)